# Getting error curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN when trying to install Homebrew in Macbook OS Venture 13.0.1

Tags: macos, curl, homebrew, libressl

Getting the Error 'curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN in connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443' in Mac Terminal when trying to install the HomeBrew.
Using Mac OS - Venture 13.0.1
I am not using any VPN/Anti virus/proxy.
Any help in resolving this error is appreciated.

si@MacBook-Pro ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -v -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

- Trying 49.205.171.201:443...
- Connected to raw.githubusercontent.com (49.205.171.201) port 443 (#0)
- ALPN: offers h2
- ALPN: offers http/1.1
- CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
- CApath: none
- (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  } [330 bytes data]
- LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN in connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN in connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443

I tried curl command with --ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 and ALL by searching in some websites, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 8):

These steps solved this problem for me

Manually configure hosts:

To modify the host's file on a macOS system:

1. Open the Finder.
2. Use the key combination Shift+Command+G to open "Go to Folder", and enter /etc/hosts in the input box. This will open the location of the host's file.
3. Copy the host's file to the desktop, right-click it, and select "Open with" - "Text Editing".
4. Open the host's file and copy in the previous content.
5. Add a new line after the host's file and enter 185.199.108.133 raw.githubusercontent.com.
6. Save the modified host file.
   Note: If you are using VS Code, you can modify and save the host's file directly in VS Code without the need to copy it to the desktop first.

You can refer to this
[link-to-solution](https://blog.csdn.net/u014163312/article/details/124783357)!

Comment: works perfectly. 
It would be great if you could explain the problem, why it is happening

Comment: Other  solution is add dns entry with 8.8.8.8 , then after it will also work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. Can you please explain why this issue is occurring though?

Comment: @SaiVamsi

https://m.timesofindia.com/gadgets-news/github-content-domain-blocked-for-these-indian-users-reports/amp_articleshow/96687992.cms

Comment: @devudilip , This link explains the problem 
[link](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/gadgets-news/github-content-domain-blocked-for-these-indian-users-reports/articleshow/96687992.cms)

Answer (score 0):

I switched from office wifi to mobile-hotspot and it worked for me